# How can I allow div to float outside the main container

Tags: css

I am working on WP using a template and I'm trying to get a button to float outside the main container. I went through some already posted questions here, but no luck.

I have tried with padding, margin, overflow, etc. The one thing that seems to work is by setting negative margin, but in that case the div is hidden by the main container.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="purchase_options_meta clearfix">
                    <div class="purchase_options">
                       <div id="deal_attributes_wrap" class="section ">                                
                        </div>
                           <div class="buy_button gb_ff font_x_large">                                
                        </div>

                    </div>
 </div>
```

And here's the CSS I'm using:

```
    .container.main {
    width: 980px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
    }

    .purchase_options {
    position: relative;
    }

    .buy_button {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(http://topgreekgyms.fitnessforum.gr/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Button12.png) no-repeat center;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 375px;
    left: -54px;
    top: -16px;
    }

    .button {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
    }

    .button:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #cccccc;
    }

    .buy_button a {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 29px;
    font-family: arial;
    padding: 12px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 0 0 50px;
    }   

    .buy_button a span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 33px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    }
```

And here's a [link](http://topgreekgyms.fitnessforum.gr/deals/test-deal-3/) to the page. My problem is with the top red button at the left.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Your link didn't post correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry about that here's the link http://topgreekgyms.fitnessforum.gr/deals/test-deal-3/

Comment: Don't post PHP, just post the relevant HTML generated by the PHP.  Also, which button are you talking about?

Comment: Chris I'm referring to the button that writes 'Αγορασέ το' and shows the price at its right.
I have found a temporary solution by changing the 'overflow' of the main container to 'visible' even that caused the container to stop expanding based on the available content ( I had set to 'auto' before)

Comment: I have also edited the both the PHP and the CSS code in my original question. Hope that makes things easier.

Comment: @kat_indo the 'Αγορασέ το' button look ok to me, is the issue trying to make that main container the same width as the top bar without breaking this overlapping effect?

Comment: Hey Adam! The problem now is that the height of the main container doesn't expand according to the content (you can see that the content of the sidebar area is overlaping with the footer).
That's caused because I changed the overflow of the main container from 'auto' to 'visible'

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that helps someone in the future:

I had to add this part of CSS in my code:

```
#deal_single.clearfix:after {
    clear: both !important;
}
```

Just to be more specific '#deal_single' is the page id.